# SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions:

Tags: apache-spark

This INFO line is getting printed when starting worker in Apache Spark.

And logs are repeating same.

When I am checking master UI, it shows one worker ALIVE.

after sometime it again shows it dead, then repeats same.

Can you please explain this behaviour

Comment: What Info? I believe you are missing something?